# Outdoor string lights plug adapter?

Tags: led, light, porch, adapter, cfl

My back porch does not have any external outlets. The porch light has this F13BX/827 double LED light, which is requires a 2 pin gx23 base. I was wondering if there are any adapters that can go into this base and have an outlet on the other side (for string lights). I know they have them for traditional incandescent bulb bases, but I wonder if anyone has found one (link, please) for the aforementioned one.

[image]

Comment: that looks like a fluorescent light

Comment: I don't know of one and would be surprised.

Comment: How is the fixture mounted? It might not be that hard to connect a receptacle in a box next to it, though it would likely end up switched along with the existing light. Also, any new outdoor receptacle (but not, generally, lighting) needs GFCI, and you can't put GFCI high up, so you would likely then need to have the circuit GFCI protected earlier (e.g., at the switch or the breaker panel or in between).

Comment: There seem to be gx23 to e27/e27 adapters.  If they are safe or legal will be up to you to find out.

Comment: I dont think so, I didnt find any for a similar situation with another fixture.  Also the rest of the fitting will probably have a ballast and starter.  Theres more to it then an adapter.

Comment: This is off topic for here.

Answer (score 1):

There may be physical adapters available, but they won't work like you expect. This socket type is connected to a ballast rather than directly to line voltage. That means even if you physically adapt the pins, you can't treat it as a regular wall outlet because of the ballast. If you want an outlet in this location you will have to change out the fixture for one that does not use a ballast, install an extension ring with an outlet (and add a GFCI) or wire in a whole new outlet and circuit. There's one other super-hacky option: you can bypass the ballast and change out the bulb for a 'ballast bypass' LED type. Then a socket adapter will work. You still won't have a GFCI, so it's of course dangerous compared to a proper outlet, but it will let you hang up string lights. Just know that it's not a great way to go because of the shock risk. Outdoor electric shock risk from plug-in devices is significant enough that GFCIs have been standard there for 30+ years.